# How do I replace multiple text at once in a file on Linux or Mac?

Tags: linux, macos

So example, I have the file my.txt as below

```
This is my xzy.
My color is white.
```

I want to replace ***"my" to our***, and I also want to replace ***"xyz" to "abc"***.

How can I do this using a one line command?

Comment: You have `xzy` in your example, but you are asking to replace `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`

For `GNU sed`

```
sed -i -e 's/my/our/g' -e 's/xyz/abc/g' my.txt
```

In MacOS, `-e` option may not be available. `-i` option in MacOS needs an extension. Use something like this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/my/our/g;s/xyz/abc/g' my.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` with multiple replacement:

`sed -i 's/my/our/g; s/xyz/abc/g' text.txt`